# Accessing a method in the class that created the class you're currently in

Tags: java, javafx, conways-game-of-life

Having a bit of trouble here. So I have two classes: A GUIBuilder and a Class that simulates Conway's Game of Life using 2D arrays. The GUI creates a grid of squares to a user's chosen dimensions and then allows them to select which squares are "alive" and "dead" to start off, they then specify how many generations the simulation will run for and hit the start simulation button. The grid of squares will update to reflect the new bounds as well as which squares are now "living" and which are "dead" for each generation.

Originally I had set up Conway's game of life class to print out the 2D array it creates for each generation as an output but now I want to call a class in GUI Builder to update a GUI grid of squares, with each square being a different colour to show its status, in place of these print outputs. A button is pressed in the GUI to call the Conway class with the specifications for the simulation then the Conway class runs the simulation pausing at the end of each generation to update the GUI to reflect the new state of the simulation.

[image: Class Interaction I'm Thinking Of]

Each time the update method is called in the GUI builder class there is a pause to show off the progression of the simulation.

I'm using JavaFX to create the GUI as well

So here is the code for the Start Simulation button event. It'll call the method in Conway passing the 2D array of all the starting universe

```
startSimulationButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(validateTextBox(genTextField))
            {
                int[][] universe = convertTo2DArray(simulationPane);
                int generations = Integer.parseInt(genTextField.getText());
                ConwayLife simStart = new ConwayLife();
                simStart.getGeneration(universe, generations);
            }
            else
            {
                instructionLabel.setText("Didn't put numbers in ya silly billy");
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the update GUI method I want to be called from the Conway class

```
private void updateSimulationPane(int[][] universe, int xUpdate, int yUpdate) throws InterruptedException
{
    clearSimulationGrid(simulationPane);
    int[] flatUniverse = Stream.of(universe).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).toArray();
    for(int counter = 0; counter < (xUpdate*yUpdate); counter++)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, squareDimensions, squareDimensions);
        if(flatUniverse[counter] == 1)
        {
            rect.setFill(Color.DARKGREEN);
        }
        else
        {
            rect.setFill(Color.GREY);
        }
        simulationPane.add(rect, (counter) % xInput, (counter) / xInput);
    }

    double leftAnchor = (xWindow / 2) - ((squareDimensions * xInput) / 2);          
    gridAnchorPane.setTopAnchor(simulationPane, 100d);
    gridAnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(simulationPane, leftAnchor);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

and finally here is the point in the Conway class that I would like to update the GUI

```
    if(deadCells == i * j) //if there are no more alive cells
        {
            int[][] emptyArray = new int[0][0];
            /*
            //******Last Generation plus Empty set output*********
            System.out.println("Generation: " + counter);
            for(int elcounto = 0; elcounto < oldGeneration.length; elcounto++)
            {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oldGeneration[elcounto]));
            }
            System.out.println("Generation: " + (counter + 1) + "\nSociety died out");
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(emptyArray));
            //****************************************************
            */

            //call updateSimulationPane here 

            return emptyArray; //return an empty set to show that the society died out


        }
        /*
        //******Generation Check Output*********
        System.out.println("Generation: " + counter);
        for(int elcounto = 0; elcounto < oldGeneration.length; elcounto++)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oldGeneration[elcounto]));
        }
        System.out.println();
        //**************************************
        */

        //call updateSimulationPane here 

        oldGeneration = newGeneration; //make the new generation the old generation to show passing of a generation
        newGeneration = new int[oldGeneration.length + bounds][oldGeneration[0].length + bounds]; //em
    }
    return trim(oldGeneration);
```

The Conway side is pretty rough the now but so long as I can call back and update the GUI I'll be able to work out all the kinks on that end. Basically just looking to fix the class interaction. I hope that's enough information to understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Just pass a reference to the instance of the class which has the `updateSimulationPane` method to the `ConwayLife` instance when you create it.

Comment: As an aside, you have some major threading issues in this code. You must never update the UI from any thread other than the FX Application Thread (because UI components are not thread-safe), and you must never block the FX Application Thread (e.g. by calling `Thread.sleep()` or performing a long-running operation). You've given no indication as to which thread `updateSimulationPane()` is running on, but it necessarily violates one of these rules.

Comment: Ah okay. I think I know of a way to adjust the code to accommodate these rules but it'll take a big redesign. I'll work on that once I've worked this naive apporach to the wall. Thank you!!

Comment: It shouldn't. If the code in the `ConwayLife` is running in a background thread, just wrap the call to `updateSimulationPane()` in `Platform.runLater()`. If you need to pause and do something after a pause, just use a `PauseTransition`.